# how to I add a database to zurb foundation?

Tags: database, frameworks, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to add a login portion on foundation and allow users to upload their own photos. how do I do that ?

if this is not the right place where to ask please redirect me

Answer (score 0):

The foundation framework is simply a tool for you to develop the "front-end" of your website or app. A database would be a "back-end" feature that you would then create a form for (front-end) to connect users to your database (back-end).

You can develop the back-end yourself or use a CMS such as wordpress which will likely already have the features you need. Hope that helps.